# vb.net directory file search with multiple wild cards

Tags: vb.net, wildcard, subdirectory

What I am trying to do is search through a folder's subdirectories and any folders that have /Year/Month/ I want to pull the files from that folder.

The folder paths are typically as follows

BaseFilePath\Group1\SubGroup1\Year\Month
BaseFilePath\Group1\Year\Month

The goal is to move those files into another folder and while I have tried iterating through the whole directory it just seems to take too long, and I was wondering if there was a quicker or easier solution.

The code I was using to do this is as follows

```
    Dim topLevelFolder As New DirectoryInfo("\\BaseFilePath\")

    Using outputFile As New StreamWriter("C:\output_file.txt")
        For Each currentFile In topLevelFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Try
                If currentFile.Directory.Name = "June" AndAlso currentFile.Directory.Parent.Name = "2014" AndAlso Left(currentFile.Name, 5) <> "SENT_" Then
                    outputFile.WriteLine(currentFile.Directory.Parent.Parent.Name & "/" & currentFile.Directory.Parent.Name & "/" & currentFile.Directory.Name & "/" & currentFile.Name)
                End If
            Catch
            End Try

        Next
    End Using
```

This portion alone is already taking close to 30 seconds, and I'd imagine moving the files to another folder is going to take some time too, but if I can speed up the finding of the files the whole process would go smoother.

I saw that you can use wildcards in the searchPattern, but when I tried I got illegal characters in path or Second path fragment must not be a drive or UNC name.  I know individual wildcards are useable ie (BaseFilePath\partialFolderName*) but doesn't seem to help when it extends to multiple directories being wildcarded.

Ideally what I'm looking to do is search BaseFilePath*2014\June* and only pull files from those folders.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
topLevelFolder.EnumerateDirectories("*2014", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Then out of those, filter `June` ones. Then enumerate files in each of the result entries.

Unfortunately, .NET does not support directory wildcard search for the full path, so this does not work `*2014\June*`, it complains about invalid characters.

Comment: topLevelFolder.EnumerateDirectories("*2014", SearchOption.AllDirectories) seems to still take up a bulk of time.  About 15-20 seconds on average for that line alone, the rest of the code below finishes within a second.

Comment: @Jerry: You can look into getting an SSD, or start using async. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719020/is-there-an-async-version-of-directoryinfo-getfiles-directory-getdirectories-i